# Prove Newton's Identities using the properties of a symmetric polynomial.

Tags: abstract-algebra, symmetric-polynomials

Apologies if I didn't explain this properly in the title. I understand how we progress from (1) down, but I don't understand how to use the coefficients of EQ 5 to prove Newton's Identities.

Let $a_1,....,a_N$ be $N$ pairwise different elements in a field, and let
    \begin{equation}
  p(x) = \prod_{u=1}^N (1-xa_u) \tag{1}
 \end{equation}
    Denoting the formal derivative of $p$ by $p'$ the (formal) logarithm derivative of $p$ is given by 
    \begin{equation}
  \frac{p'(x)}{p(x)} = -\sum_{u=1}^N \frac{a_u}{1-xa_u} \tag{2}
 \end{equation}
    and so
    \begin{equation}
  \frac{xp'(x)}{p(x)} = -\sum_{u=1}^N \frac{xa_u}{1-xa_u} = -\sum_{n=0}^\infty x^n S_n \tag{3}
 \end{equation}
    where
    \begin{equation}
  S_n = \sum_{u=1}^N a_{u}^n , n = 1,2,....., \tag{4}
 \end{equation}
    $i.e.$
    \begin{equation}
  xp'(x) = -p(x)(\sum_{n=0}^\infty x^n S_n) \tag{5}
 \end{equation}
    write
    \begin{equation}
  p(x) = \sum_{n=0}^N x^n (-1)^n \sigma_{n} \tag{6}
 \end{equation}
    where $\sigma_0 = 1$ and where the coefficients $\sigma_n$ for $n \geq 1$ are the symmetric functions of the roots. We have
    \begin{equation}
  \sigma_1 = \sum_{u=1}^N a_u  
 \end{equation}
    \begin{equation}
  \sigma_2 = \sum_{u_1 < u_2}^N a_{u_1}a_{u_2} \tag{7}
 \end{equation}
    \begin{equation}
  \sigma_3 = \sum_{u_1 < u_2 < u_3}^N a_{u_1}a_{u_2} a_{u_3}
 \end{equation}
By Comparing the coefficients of $x^n$ in $(5)$, prove Newton's identities
\begin{equation}
r\sigma_r = \sum_{i+j=r} \sigma_i \lambda_j
\end{equation}

Comment: When you say you don't understand how to use "that" to prove Newton's identities, what does "that" refer to? Please be more clear and explicit in saying what it is you don't understand.

Comment: @runway44 comparing the coefficients of x^n in eq. 5 to prove the identities. Sorry, I thought that would be clear, I'll make it more obvious.

Comment: @ancientmathematician $\lambda_i$ isn't defined anywhere and it's written down as a $+$ not $=$ in the text. https://imgur.com/VRx0ail

Comment: With a $+$ it's a formula  not an identity. This must be a typo.

Comment: The $\lambda_j$ are just the $S_j$, and there's an assumption that $\sigma_r=0$ for $r>N$.

Comment: Well, examine equation (5). What are the terms on the left? What are the terms on the right?

Comment: @ancientmathematician yep, but even in a corrected form $r\sigma_r = \sum_{i+j=r} \sigma_i  \lambda_i$, it doesn't look like one of Newton's Identities? Granted it's not something I've been exposed to very much.

Comment: It looks to me exactly like Newton's Identities. Look at the Wikipedia page.

Comment: @ancientmathematician Where does the assumption that $\sigma_r = 0 for r > N$ come from? If we know that $\sigma_0 = 1 when n \geq 1$ won't we end up broken equality and a case where 0 is equal to something greater than 0?

Comment: Look: just do the thing by hand for the case $N=3$ and you'll see the pattern. Surely $\sigma_0=N$?

Comment: I took out the `finite-fields` and `coding-theory` tags and replaced them with some that are more relevant. If there is a connection to one of these topics, you should mention that (e.g. are you assuming your field is finite?)

Comment: @MorganRodgers the question specifies a finite number of pairwise elements contained in a field, doesn't that meet the requirements of finite-fields?

Comment: @Propagating No not at all. You could have a finite subset of $\mathbb{Q}$ or $\mathbb{R}$. A finite field is a field containing only a finite number of elements.

Comment: @MorganRodgers oh, I see it now, thanks. sorry for the confusion, this question came out of nowhere in a study guide unrelated to the course so most of it's foreign

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I will use $e_n$ and $p_n$ for elementary and power-sum symmetric polynomials respectively:

$$ \begin{array}{lll}
 e_k(x_1,x_2,\cdots,x_n) & = & \displaystyle \hskip -0.1in \sum_{1\le i_1<\cdots<i_k\le n} \hskip -0.2in x_{i_{\large1}}x_{i_{\large2}}\cdots x_{i_{\large k}} \\[10pt]
 p_k(x_1,x_2,\cdots,x_n) & = & \hskip 0.17in \displaystyle \sum_{1\le i\le n} x_i^k
\end{array} $$

Then we can define the function

$$ f(T)=\prod_{1\le i\le n}(1-x_iT). $$

Vieta's formulas say this can be expanded as

$$ f(T) = \sum_{k=0}^n (-1)^ke_{k}(x_1,\cdots,x_n)T^k. $$

Differentiate (with respect to $T$) and then multiply by $T$:

$$ Tf'(T)=\sum_{k=1}^n (-1)^k e_k kT^k. \tag{$\star$} $$

We're told that this is part of an identity

$$ Tf'(T)=-f(T)\left(\sum_{j=1}^{\infty} p_jT^j\right).   \tag{5} $$

We can multiply out the polynomials on the right side as

$$ -\left(\sum_{i=0}^n (-1)^ie_iT^i \right)
\left(\sum_{j=1}^{\infty} p_jT^j\right) = -\sum_{i=0}^{\infty}\sum_{j=1}^{\infty} (-1)^ie_ip_j T^{i+j} $$

$$ = \sum_{k=0}^{\infty} \left(\sum_{\substack{i+j=k}} (-1)^{i+1} e_ip_j\right)T^k \tag{$\circ$} $$

For convenience, I've extended the summation from $0\le i\le n$ to $i\ge0$ by stipulating $e_i=0$ for $i>n$; there shouldn't be any summands in that case and the so-called "empty sum" is zero.

In equation $(5)$ we can replace the left side with $(\star)$ and the right side with $(\circ)$:

$$ \sum_{k=1}^n (-1)^k e_k kT^k = \sum_{k=0}^{\infty} \left(\sum_{i+j=k} (-1)^{i+1}e_ip_j\right)T^k. $$

Both sides are the same polynomial so they must have the same coefficients.

The coefficient of $T^r$ on the left and right sides are:

$$ (-1)^r e_r r = \sum_{i+j=r} (-1)^{i+1} e_i p_j $$

Dividing both sides by $(-1)^r$ we get

$$ re_r = \sum_{i+j=r} (-1)^{j+1} e_i p_j $$

The signs are supposed to be alternating; a $(-1)$ is missing from your statement of Newton-Girard. Also keep in mind $i\ge0$ and $j\ge1$ in the summation.

Comment: Thank you, I still don't fully understand it but it's a bit more clear now.